# Adding new values to mysql database no longer possible?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Hi guys please consider the code below. I was using it to add new values to my table(`booking`) in mysql database(`seat_booking`).

Variables include `String(id,cname,ctype,event_name)` and `int(seatsno)`.I also call a function `EventName()` in this code and, trust me guys it works perfectly and I am able to derive the event name from the another table(events) but the only problem arises in this method.

Guys my project is to make a seat booking GUI app so this code does work when I used it to add new events for the "Admin" mode but doesn't work here ,i.e., when I need it to store the booking values for a particular customer. Please help guys. I would really appreciate it.

```
private void newbookbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/seat_booking","root","<mypassword>");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM booking";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        String cname = tfcname.getText();
        int seatsno = Integer.parseInt(tfseatsno.getText());
        String evtname = EventName();
        String ctype = "Normal Customer"; long bookid = getID();
        String id = Long.toString(bookid); 
        String query1="insert into booking values('"+ id +"','"+ cname +"','"+ ctype +"','"+evtname+"',"+ seatsno+");";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Booking successfull!");
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error encountered while booking new event!");
    }
}
```

I have tried putting the `e.Stacktrace();` statement in the application and I ran it the following was the resulting output for error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Track Events Warm-up,1)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
    at CustomerNewBook.newbookbtnActionPerformed(CustomerNewBook.java:256)
    at CustomerNewBook.access$100(CustomerNewBook.java:16)
    at CustomerNewBook$2.actionPerformed(CustomerNewBook.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
...
```

Comment: what is the error you are having?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent sqlinjection

Comment: print out the stacktrace and share it

Comment: @Jens bro i am not able to use `e.printStacktrace();` it shows warning that variable not found

Comment: @mc20 the system is showing me that I have some problem with my sql syntax in the code line `String query1 =.....` at the last near evtname and seatsno . Do you mind checking and telling me if you find anything wrong with it?

Comment: This query urgently needs **placeholder values** so you can avoid syntax and escaping problems relating to that. [It's not that hard](http://bobby-tables.com/java) to do.

Comment: @JayantPanwar Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Comment: Done i did it @RoshanaPitigala

Comment: @JayantPanwar click on the tick on the left to accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong driver class. correct is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

`java.sql.Driver` is only an Interface. For more informations see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html)

BTW: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent sqlinjection
Do not supress error Messages. Atleast log them or put it into the message Dialog:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStacktrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error encountered while booking new event!"+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: ok i tried what you said and the error message says that I have a problem with my sql syntax near evtname and seatsno in the statement which reads ----> 'String query1 =........'           Can you check that line and tell what's wrong with that line @Jens?

Comment: @JayantPanwar Please add the compplete stacktrace to your question

Comment: as per your advice I have edited the question and added the complete stacktrace in it. plz have look

Comment: @JayantPanwar Because you are not using prepared Statements, you have to escape single quotes in your value!! That are Special characters vvalue contains `'s Track Events Warm-up,1)`

Comment: as per your advice I removed all the single quotes from the `String query1 =....` line but I must say that error encountered remains the same! i.e.
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer,Women's High Jump Warm-up,6)' at line 1`

Comment: @JayantPanwar Not from the query string. only from the values `'Customer,Women's High Jump Warm-up,6)'`  --->`'Customer,Women''s High Jump Warm-up,6)'` OR `'Customer,Womens High Jump Warm-up,6)' `

Comment: So you mean to say I must update my database and change all events where I used single quotes to double quotes? Ok I will try that but like I said earlier in my question this code works when i use it in a different part of this application even with single quotes

Comment: @ Jens I removed **single quotes** from my values in the table but I am still getting the same error message, what 2 do now??
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer,Womens High Jump Warm-up,2)' at line 1`

Comment: @JayantPanwar Not in the table. in `evtname`

Comment: so i have to find single quote in the `evtname` first and then delete it? Do you mind telling me how to remove single quote from it given that the String could be any of 10 different events

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2 <sup>(for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428077/adding-new-values-to-mysql-database-no-longer-possible/52428302?#comment91830648_52428302))</sup> :**

Check the error,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near `s Track Events Warm-up,1)` ...

The problem is with the Strings that you are passing. Make sure any of your variables (`id, cname, ctype, evtname`) doesn't contain single qoutes(`'`) or any other escape characters which may disturb the query.

This problem would easily be solved by using [Prepared Statements](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface). Try,

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO `booking` VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query1);  
stmt.setString(1, id); //1 specifies the first parameter in the query  
stmt.setString(2, cname);
stmt.setString(3, ctype);
stmt.setString(4, evtname);
stmt.setInt(5, seatsno); //use setInt() to parse ints
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

---

**Update <sup>(for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428077/adding-new-values-to-mysql-database-no-longer-possible/52428302#comment91802199_52428302))</sup>:**

In your `catch` block, comment the `JOptionPane` line and add the following,

```
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ...);
}
```

then run your application once again and update the question with the error output.

---

**Original answer :**

If you are using `jdbc:mysql` you need the MySQL connector.

- Download it from [mysql-connector-java-8.0.12](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.zip),
- Add the `mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar` to your project.
- Change the driver class,

  ```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  ```
- Clean and build <sup>(Optional but recommended)</sup>.

Comment: bro i tried what you said but it doesn't work still error in booking new event

Comment: the `e.printStackTrace();` line shows warning in netbeans. It says that the variable name printStackTrace can't be found. Maybe i am inputting it wrong, can you give the entire line which should be written.

Comment: @JayantPanwar The warning is given to remind you that `printStackTrace()` should be removed. Don't pay attention to the warning. just put the line after `catch`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete stacktrace in it as you said. Plz have a look

Comment: @JayantPanwar Check my answer now